# How to tell a user that someone has logged in with thier account?

Tags: php, laravel

Good day, I am using `logoutOtherDevices()` on in my **LoginController**:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // Some pieces of code...
    
    // Logout other session.
    Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request['password']);
}
```

I would like to implement  flash message that will prompt the forced logged out user that someone has logged in with their account.

Comment: store the user ip address and then check if user have same ip then continue with login else logout the user mostly google do the same when we login from different device

Comment: An ip address check is often not good enough, because it can be manipulated or represents several users behind a company network.

Comment: I also thought about using IP address but realized maybe a company is behind a NAT or something that will only represent them as a single IP.